# How to create a long-form data frame from a 3D array (for a facet plot of histograms)

Tags: r, arrays, ggplot2, pivot, histogram

I’m running some simulation tests where I vary each of two parameters (“x” and “y”) across respective ranges -- and then compute a resulting error score for each combination of parameters. I run this simulation a bunch of times, and I want to visualize the distribution of error scores for each x/y combination across the sims.

The code below implements this, but the way I create a long-form data frame (for ggplot) is *way* too kludgy and “manual.” Yes, there’s a pattern I’m using to create the x, y, and z long-form column values from the array dimensions. But, ugh!

(Also, I lose the array’s dimension names when I wrestle it into a long-form data frame via a vector conversion.)

```
### Create a 3D array of "errors"
# - The first two dimensions are for variation across params "x" and "y"
# - The third dimension, "z", represents sim runs for each x/y combination
dims <- c(2, 3, 50) 
# The means around which my simulated errors will vary
errorMeans <- 1:(prod(dims[1:2])) 
# Generate "errors" (varying around the errorMeans)
errorVec <- rnorm(prod(dims), mean=errorMeans, sd=0.4)
# My "starting point": A 2D array of error scores, across sims (the 3rd dim)
errorArray <- array(errorVec, 
                    dims, 
                    dimnames=list(x=1:dims[1], y=1:dims[2], z=1:dims[3]))

### Create a long-form data frame from the 3D array
# Read the array into a vector
errorVec <- as.vector(errorArray)
# Write the vector to a long-form data frame (my approach: ugh!) 
dfLong <- data.frame(error=errorVec, 
                    x=rep(1:dims[1], prod(dims[2:3])), 
                    y=rep(rep(1:dims[2], each=dims[1]), dims[3]),
                    z=rep(1:dims[1], each=prod(dims[2:3])))

### Create a faceted histogram plot, showing error variation across the sims (the 3rd dim, "z")
plt <- ggplot(data=dfLong, aes(x=error)) +
  geom_histogram(fill="steelblue") + 
  facet_grid(vars(x), vars(y))
plot(plt)
```

[Faceted histogram of variation in array dimension "z" for all combinations of dimensions "x" and "y"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2zu9.jpg)

There must be a way to use, say, dplyr’s pivot_longer()? I just can’t figure out how to do so from a (3D) array, vs. from a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df2 <- reshape2::melt(errorArray)
```

This will reduce the dimensions of your object and add them as a column:

```
## Your solution:
    > head(dfLong)
          error x y z
    1 0.7056645 1 1 1
    2 1.7947472 2 1 1
    3 2.2723746 1 2 1
    4 4.0289590 2 2 1
    5 4.9018582 1 3 1
    6 5.3910886 2 3 1


## My solution:     
> head(df2) # My 
      x y z     value
    1 1 1 1 0.7056645
    2 2 1 1 1.7947472
    3 1 2 1 2.2723746
    4 2 2 1 4.0289590
    5 1 3 1 4.9018582
    6 2 3 1 5.3910886
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way, commented in the code.

```r
set.seed(2023)    # make results reproducible

dims <- c(2, 3, 50) 
# The means around which my simulated errors will vary
errorMeans <- 1:(prod(dims[1:2])) 
# Generate "errors" (varying around the errorMeans)
errorVec <- rnorm(prod(dims), mean=errorMeans, sd=0.4)
# My "starting point": A 2D array of error scores, across sims (the 3rd dim)
errorArray <- array(errorVec, 
                    dims, 
                    dimnames=list(x=1:dims[1], y=1:dims[2], z=1:dims[3]))

# question's code
errorVec <- as.vector(errorArray)
# Write the vector to a long-form data frame (my approach: ugh!) 
dfLong <- data.frame(error=errorVec, 
                     x=rep(1:dims[1], prod(dims[2:3])), 
                     y=rep(rep(1:dims[2], each=dims[1]), dims[3]),
                     z=rep(1:dims[1], each=prod(dims[2:3])))


# create a data.frame of x, y, z values
dfRui <- do.call(expand.grid, lapply(dim(errorArray), seq))
dfRui <- cbind.data.frame(error = c(errorArray), dfRui)
names(dfRui)[-1] <- c("x", "y", "z")
# see what dfRui looks like
head(dfRui, n = 10)
#>        error x y z
#> 1  0.9664863 1 1 1
#> 2  1.6068225 2 1 1
#> 3  2.2499731 1 2 1
#> 4  3.9255421 2 2 1
#> 5  4.7466057 1 3 1
#> 6  6.4363190 2 3 1
#> 7  0.6345091 1 1 2
#> 8  2.4006559 2 1 2
#> 9  2.8402934 1 2 2
#> 10 3.8127508 2 2 2


# we don't need the z column to be what the question's code create
identical(dfLong[-4], dfRui[-4])
#> [1] TRUE

# plot code, copy & paste from the question
library(ggplot2)

plt <- ggplot(data = dfLong, aes(x = error)) +
  geom_histogram(fill = "steelblue") + 
  facet_grid(vars(x), vars(y))
plot(plt)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly simpler method in base R:

```
> cbind(expand.grid(dimnames(errorArray)),v=c(errorArray))|>head()
  x y z        v
1 1 1 1 1.303021
2 2 1 1 2.137265
3 1 2 1 4.071997
4 2 2 1 3.956908
5 1 3 1 4.853801
6 2 3 1 5.905643
```

Or you can also convert the array first to a table and then to a dataframe, but it converts the dimension names to factors:

```
> as.data.frame(as.table(errorArray))|>head()
  x y z     Freq
1 1 1 1 1.303021
2 2 1 1 2.137265
3 1 2 1 4.071997
4 2 2 1 3.956908
5 1 3 1 4.853801
6 2 3 1 5.905643
```